# Extra expression in method definition

Tags: ruby, class, methods

In this example, the last `english` in the method definition seems to be unnecessary to me. I took it out and the code worked just as fine. Why does the book include it? Is there some sort of convention I am unaware of?

```
class Integer
  def to_eng
    if self == 5
      english = 'five'
    else
      english = 'fifty-eight'
    end
    english  
  end
end

#  I'd better test on a couple of numbers...
puts 5.to_eng
puts 58.to_eng
```

Comment: It's computationally equivalent but more clearly expresses your meaning to a human.  Relatedly, it also protects you in case the code above changes.

Comment: More than that — the variable's existence is pointless. You could replace the method body with `if self == 5 then 'five' else 'fifty-eight' end`.

Comment: @Darshan, I respectfully disagree.  All those unnecessary lines of code and the unnecessary local variable are just clutter.  Imo, readers can parse `self == 5 ? 'five' : 'fifty-eight'` (as suggested by @Donatas) a lot faster, with less chance of misreading.  As for repeating the variable at the end to protect one against changes to the code, it could have the opposite effect.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I absolutely agree with you if that part of the method is up for grabs.  I was assuming this was a simplified example for asking the question about the value of the final `english` statement.  There are many methods that look like this, where it is not computationally necessary to place a final statement but it is done so for clarity, and I was trying to explain that rationale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ensures that the value in local variable 'english' is returned. The last executed statement in a method is what's returned.

In this case, it's not needed, but if (for example) the method was rewritten as...

```
def to_eng
  english = 'fifty-eight'
  english = 'five' if self == 5
end
```

... you would find that nothing gets returned for any number other than 5 because the last statement... not being executed... would just return nil.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, the result of the last statement is always returned from the function. In this case the result is the value of the 'english' variable. However if we remove the last line of the method it still behaves the same because both lines returns the value that is set on 'english' variable.

```
english = 'five' #=> 'five'
english = 'fifty-eight' #=> 'fifty-eight'
```

Also this method could be written in more compact and elegant way using a ternary operator.

```
class Integer
  def to_eng
    self == 5 ? 'five' : 'fifty-eight'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The best reason for me is debuggability. In the showcased code, you can insert a debug statement just before the return, and know the result:

```
class Integer

  def to_eng
    if self == 5
      english = 'five'
    else
      english = 'fifty-eight'
    end

    debugger
    # or: puts "ENGLISH IS #{english}"
    # or: binding.pry
    # or whatever else you want

    english  
  end

end
```

You can't do that if you leave off the last `english`, because the return value would change.